# Modifying the contents of a closure

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there a better way to do it than:

```
|aBlock|
aBlock := [3+2].
aBlock := Object readFrom: (a printString copyReplaceAll: '3' with: '2').
```

?

**EDIT** This code was just an example, what about things like:

```
[:something | 
    something checkSomethingElse ifNil: 
        [whatever] 
    ifNotNil:
        [something getSomethingDone]]
```

Where now I want to checkAnotherThing instead of checkSomethingElse.

or:

```
[:oneParameter :anotherParameter | 
    oneParameter doSomethingWith: anotherParameter]
```

Where now I want to add a third parameter and:

```
[:oneParameter :anotherParameter :yetAnotherParameter | 
    oneParameter doSomethingWith: anotherParameter and: yetAnotherParameter]
```

Comment: Because, in Smalltalk, I can :P

Comment: You can use #perform: and co. to change the test method. Hence: `[:something :selectorCheck | (something perform: selectorCheck ) ifNil: [] ... ]`.

Comment: For variable size parameter use the `#perform:WithArgs:` method. You can also use block  `[:what | what value ifNil: [] ... ]`. The idea here is that there is many way to achieve things in Smalltalk. But changing the source code and do the evaluation should be reserve to extreme case. (If you are writing an interpreter of some kind.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialising a Block as a string and doing string manipulations, while handy, is also quite dangerous if you don't have a very clear idea of the contents of the Block.

It sounds like you'd like to be able to manipulate the AST of the block - given a block, parse it, change the structure (replacing the literal, in this case) and then compile the changed structure. To that end, you could do something like this:

```
| aBlock ast |
aBlock := [3+2].
ast := aBlock decompile.
ast statements first receiver: (DecompilerConstructor new codeAnyLiteral: 4).
aBlock := (Compiler evaluate: ast printString) first.
aBlock value. "==> 6"
```

Note that we're not actually altering aBlock, but creating a *mutated copy* of aBlock.

The principle applies more generally: decompile the block, do your manipulation (changing the selector halfway through a chain of message sends, for instance), compile the new parse tree. (I don't know off-hand how to compile the tree *directly* rather than evaluating the printed out tree, but I'm sure there's a way.)

(Caveat: I've written the above in Squeak. I don't know the state of play with Opal, Pharo's new compiler, so perhaps you'd do something slightly different in Pharo.)

Answer (score 2):

```
In Pharo:

| aBlock   x |

x := 1.

aBlock := [ x := x + 1].

Transcript show: aBlock value printString; cr.

x := 41.

Transcript show: aBlock value printString; cr.
```

Comment: That doesn't modify the block at all... I meant modify as in MyClass compile: aMethod, but for a closure.

Comment: Well, sure it does not modify block, but it modifies how existing block behaves. And if someone holds a reference to the block it will observer different behavior between valuations, which is to him pretty much the same as if the block has changed. Note that I would rarely choose such behavior in my code, and would much prefer factory block like Lukas has suggested. Blocks that change their behavior smell of globals :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use reflection to manipulate blocks, but the cleanest solution is to dynamically bind values in your block by wrapping it with another block:

```
factory := [ :a :b | [ a + b ] ].
```

The `factory` produces blocks where a and b are bound to different values:

```
aBlock := factory value: 3 value: 2.
```

Evaluating `aBlock` answers `5`.

Comment: I should explain myself. The previous code was just an example, what I meant is how does one use reflection to manipulate blocks :)